# Get multiple values between brackets

Tags: regex, bash, brackets

I want to retrieve multiple strings between brackets. Here is the command I use for now:

```
grep '\[*\]' src/config/mail.ini
```

It returns me output like:

```
[GLOBAL]
[MAIL_1]
```

How could I get the result one by one? And, in this case, as two variables?

Comment: `grep -o '\[[^][]*]' src/config/mail.ini`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/P5Ela0).

Comment: How could I loop and, for example, display result one by one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
grep -o '\[[^][]*]' src/config/mail.ini
```

See the [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/P5Ela0)

The `-o` option makes `grep` extract the matched substrings instead of printing matching lines, and the `\[[^][]*]` pattern matches:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^][]*` - 0 or more chars other than `]` and `[` ("smart placement" is used, the `]` at the start of the bracket expression is treated as `]` and the `[` char is not special inside a bracket expression)
- `]` - a `]` char (no need to escape `]`).

To process match by match:

```
while read -r line ; do
    echo "Processing $line"
    # your code goes here
done < <(grep -o '\[[^][]*]' src/config/mail.ini)
```